Exponential of a particular block matrix
Let $C=\begin{bmatrix}A&B\\\text{Id}_{n\times n}&\bar{0}_{n\times n}\end{bmatrix}$ be a $2n\times 2n$ square matrix, such that $A$ is a diagonal matrix and $B$ is symmetric, is there any formula to compute
$$
\text{Exp}\left(tC\right)=\text{Exp}\left(t\begin{bmatrix}A&B\\\text{Id}_{n\times n}&\bar{0}_{n\times n}\end{bmatrix}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^k}{k!}\left(\begin{bmatrix}A&B\\\text{Id}_{n\times n}&\bar{0}_{n\times n}\end{bmatrix}\right)^k
$$
simmilar to this problem: Exponential of a block matrix ?
Thanks!

Use induction to compute $C^{k}$.

Even for $n=1$, the expressions I obtained on mathematica is quite complicated. Is there a reason you expect the closed form for general $n$ to be simple?

Using the block matrix determinant formula, the characteristic polynomial of $C$ is
$$ \det(C - \lambda I) = \det(\lambda^2 I -\lambda A - B) $$
That's a polynomial $P(\lambda)$ of degree $2n$ that may well be irreducible over the rationals, even if the elements of $A$ and $B$ are integers.  There's no reason to think that it is solvable by radicals if $n \ge 3$.  For example, I tried $$ A = \pmatrix{1 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 2 & 0\cr  0 & 0 & 3\cr},\ B = \pmatrix{-1 & 2 & 1\cr 2 & 3 & 3\cr 1 & 3 & 0\cr}$$
and got $P(\lambda) = \lambda^{6}-6 \lambda^{5}+9 \lambda^{4}+\lambda^{3}-20 \lambda^{2}+32 \lambda -18  $ which Maple tells me has Galois group $S_6$.
If you diagonalize $C$ as $S D S^{-1}$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix whose diagonal elements are the eigenvalues of $C$ (the roots of $P(\lambda)$, then
$\exp(tC) = S \exp(tD) S^{-1}$, where $\exp(tD)$ is diagonal with diagonal entry $\exp(t\lambda)$ corresponding to the diagonal entry $\lambda$ of $D$.  But if
the $\lambda$'s can't be expressed by radicals, I don't see how you're going to get a nice closed form for $\exp(tC)$.

Just like in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2436976/exponential-of-a-block-matrix, isn't there any way to decompose $C$ into a matrix structure of the form $C=P\cdot D\cdot P^{-1}$ such that $D=\begin{bmatrix}E&F\\bar{0}_{n\times n}&G\end{bmatrix}$ for some square matrices $E,F,G$?

Nothing simple.  In your case you'd have $\det(C - \lambda I) = \det(D - \lambda I) = \det(E - \lambda I) \det(G - \lambda I)$, but in my example $\det(C - \lambda I)$ does not factor over the rationals.
